# How I can apply antialiasing to isometric grid lines in a shader?

Tags: glsl, shader, antialiasing, isometric

I have an isometric grid shader that looks like this when zoomed out

[image]

Those gaps should not be there and lines should look smooth. How I can apply antialising to this?

This is the code I have to make this isometric grid

```
const float tileSize = 0.04;
const float borderSize = 0.98;

vec2 aGrid(vec2 uv) {
  return vec2(mod(uv.x, 1.0), mod(uv.y * 2.0, 1.0));
}

vec2 bGrid(vec2 uv) {
  return vec2(mod(uv.x - 0.5, 1.0), mod((uv.y * 2.0) - 0.5, 1.0));
}

float los(vec2 pos, float border) {
  vec2 abspos = abs(pos - vec2(0.5));
  return sign(abspos.x * border + abspos.y * border - border * border);
}

void mainImage(out vec4 fragColor, in vec2 fragCoord) {
  vec2 uv = fragCoord / iResolution.xy;
  float border = 0.5 * borderSize;
  vec2 size = (uv / tileSize) / 2.0;
  float alos = los(aGrid(size), border);
  float blos = los(bGrid(size), border);
  float color = min(alos, blos);
  fragColor = vec4(color);
}
```

Here is running in shadertoy https://www.shadertoy.com/view/slBBz3

I found this other shader for an antialiased rectangle grid https://www.shadertoy.com/view/7lBBz3 I tried to apply the same technique but I can't find how

Comment: if I see it right alos and blos is distance to the grid lines? if true based on its value you can mix the color between border and color line linearly (by converting it to parameter in range `<0 , 1>` ... also what is border? its line width or grid cell size?

Comment: border is line width

Comment: if you use too big range of zooms then maybe you should multiply the line width with your zoom (so the line width will keep constant regardless of zoom)...

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to simplify your code. Use the [Linear equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_equation) to calculate a line depending on the x-coordinate of the fragment:

```c
float y = uv.x * 0.5;
```

Calculate the distance to the y-coordinate of the fragment and get the rest of the division with the tile size:

```c
return mod(uv.y - y, tileSize);
```

Compute the absolute distance to the center of the line:

```c
float d_abs = abs(d - tileSize*0.5);
```

Use [`smoothstep`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/smoothstep.xhtml) for antialiasing:

```c
return smoothstep(0.0, borderSize, borderSize*2.0-d_abs);
```

---

Minimal example:

[image]

```c
const float tileSize = 0.1;
const float borderSize = 0.001;

float aGrid(vec2 uv) {
    float y = uv.x * -0.5;
    return mod(uv.y - y, tileSize);
}

float bGrid(vec2 uv) {
    float y = uv.x * 0.5;
    return mod(uv.y - y, tileSize);
}

float los(float d) {
    float d_abs = abs(d - tileSize*0.5);
    return smoothstep(0.0, borderSize, borderSize*2.0-d_abs);
}

void mainImage(out vec4 fragColor, in vec2 fragCoord) {
    vec2 uv = fragCoord / iResolution.xy;
    float alos = los(aGrid(uv));
    float blos = los(bGrid(uv));
    float color = max(alos, blos);
    fragColor = vec4(color);
}
```

Comment: thank you, I tried yout soultion and it looks better but I still get a similar effect when the camera zooms out a lot

Comment: Which "camera"? Which "zoom"? There is just `tileSize` and `borderSize`. If `borderSize` gets too small, you won't see anything.

Comment: I'm using a projection matrix in the vertex that makes everything small

Comment: @ellipticaldoor The projection matrix does not change `vec2 uv = fragCoord / iResolution.xy;`